# how to do server side api validation in laravel 5.4

Tags: api, laravel-5.4

How to send send error message in json format to postman in laravel 5.4

```
 //Controller
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'department_name'  => 'required',
     ]);
     if($validator->fails())
     {
        return $validator->errors()->all();
     }
     Department::create($request->all());

     return Response::json(['message' => 'Added','status' => 201],201);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use response json like this : `if ($validator->fails()) {    
    return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
}` or a status other than 200 then in the client side test if status equal the new value then show errors !

Comment: No Maraboc it dint work, I'm getting an exception if I add validation, anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: What kind of exception ?? try this one `if ($validator->fails()) { return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]); }` !!

Comment: It's working now Maraboc,Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return the validation errors as json response like this :

```
if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]); 
}
```